# How to compare two Foreach loops

Tags: windows, powershell

My current script checks if a specific folder on some clients exists.
I'd like to check if the client is online or offline before checking if the folder exists.
My current script looks like this:

```sh
$CDS = Get-content C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Clientliste.txt

Foreach($c in $CDS) {

    IF (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $c -Quiet) {
            
        Foreach ($c in $CDS) {
            $Test = Test-Path -path "\\$c\c$\apps\perl"
            Start-Sleep -s 0.25 

            If ($Test -eq $True) {
                Write-Host "Path exists on $c."
            }
            Else {
                Write-Host "Path NOT exist on $c."
            }
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "The remote computer " $c " is Offline"
    }
}
```

I don't know how to link the `foreach` loops so that they work together.
Because when I run my script now, it goes after the first `if` request in the 2nd `foreach` loop and it does leave it first, when it finishes the 2nd `foreach` loop.
I don't want that. I want that if the client is online, it checks if the paths exists and then goes to the next client and checks again if it is online and then...

Maybe you can help me :)

Comment: add a `break` in your `if`

Comment: You don't need the second foreach, remove it

Comment: You can honestly get away with just testing the path. Just cause you can ping a machine, doesn't mean you can connect to it. Only one loop is needed from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Why do another identical loop over the items from the text file is you have already tested the machine is reachable?

Just remove that second loop and do:

```
$CDS = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\XY\Desktop\Clientliste.txt'
foreach($computer in $CDS) {
    if (Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) {
        if (Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\C$\apps\perl" -PathType Container) {
            Write-Host "Path exists on computer '$computer'."
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Path NOT exist on computer '$computer'."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "The remote computer '$computer' is Offline"
    }
}
```